# URLConnection created through OkHttp has useCache set to false

Tags: java, github-api, urlconnection, okhttp

I am using the [Kohsuke GitHub-API](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/index.html) to connect to the GitHub from my Java (server-side) application and I wanted to use the [OkHttp's](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) ability to cache responses from the GitHub. This worked perfectly when I wrote a test for it, but it doesn't work in the application itself and I don't have a clue why that is. I have managed to trace the problem back to the creation of the URLConnection object that is created with its useCache variable set to false, but I cannot figure out why. Does it maybe have something to do with the server configuration or something like that?

I would appreciate any ideas or even a nudge in any direction, because frankly I don't have any ideas left... Thanks

Provider:

```
public class GitHubProvider implements Provider<GitHub> {

@Override
public GitHub get() {
    GitHub gitHub = null;
    HttpResponseCache cache = null;

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    File cacheDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    try {
        cache = new HttpResponseCache(cacheDir, 10L * 1024 * 1024);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // NOTHING
    }
    okHttpClient.setResponseCache(cache);

    try {
        gitHub = GitHub.connectUsingPassword("user", "password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // NOTHING
    }
    gitHub.setConnector(new OkHttpConnector(okHttpClient));

    return gitHub;
}
}
```

Test (works):

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class SoftwareComponentServiceTest {

public static class Module extends TestModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureTest() {
        bind(GitHub.class).toProvider(GitHubProvider.class);
    }
}

@Inject
GitHub gitHub;

@Test
public void testInjectedGitHubResponseCache() {
    try {
        GHUser ghUser = gitHub.getUser("user");
        GHRepository repository = ghUser.getRepository("repository");

        int limit = gitHub.getRateLimit().remaining;
        repository.getFileContent("README.md");

        assertEquals(limit - 1, gitHub.getRateLimit().remaining);

        repository.getFileContent("README.md");

        assertEquals(limit - 1, gitHub.getRateLimit().remaining);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Service that is used in the application (doesn't work):

```
@Singleton
@RequiresAuthentication
public class SoftwareComponentService {

@Inject
GitHub gitHub;

public List<SoftwareComponent> findAll() {
    List<SoftwareComponent> softwareComponentList = new ArrayList<SoftwareComponent>();

    try {
        GHUser ghUser = gitHub.getUser("user");
        List<GHRepository> repositories = ghUser.listRepositories().asList();

        for (int i = 0; i < repositories.size(); i++) {
            GHRepository repository = repositories.get(i);
            if (!repository.getName().startsWith("sc_")) {
                continue;
            }
            softwareComponentList.add(new SoftwareComponent(repository.getName(), repository.getDescription()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // NOTHING
    }
    return softwareComponentList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The reason

The URLConnection object is created with its **useCache** variable set to *false* because its **defaultUseCaches** variable is also set to *false* by the **Tomcat server** at the time of initialization. Tomcat does this through its **JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener** class because [reading resources from JAR files using java.net.URLConnections can sometimes result in the JAR file being locked](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JRE_Memory_Leak_Prevention_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener) (**urlCacheProtection** variable). The workaround they implemented to solve this problem was to disable URLConnection caching by default (!?!?).

## The solution

The workaround to this workaround is to create a *dummy* URLConnection and use its setDefaultUseCaches() method to [change the default value of every subsequently created URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getDefaultUseCaches%28%29) (as suggested by Jesse Wilson).

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file://dummy.jar!/");
URLConnection uConn = url.openConnection();
uConn.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
```

**Big thanks to Jesse Wilson for pointing me in the right direction!**

Answer (score 1):

There's an insane method called `URLConnection.setDefaultUseCaches()` that could be doing it globally. That's an instance method that works like a static method: it sets the property for everyone.

Comment: URLConnection.setDefaultUseCaches() method is not a static one and sadly I do not have the access to the URLConnection instance that OkHttp is using to establish the connection.

Comment: Yeah, that API is quite broken. You should be able to create _any_ URLConnection instance to do it. Even a JAR URLConnection could do it:

    getClass().getResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class").openConnection().setDefaultUseCaches(false);

Comment: Thanks! I created a dummy URLConnection (using a dummy .jar file) and used the setDefaultUseCaches() method like you suggested and it worked. `URL url = new URL("jar:file://dummy.jar!/"); URLConnection uConn = url.openConnection(); uConn.setDefaultUseCaches(true);` I also found the cause of this behavior - [Tomcat enables urlCacheProtection](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html).